# Find unused contacts

Tags: contacts, delete

As I've moved from phone to phone over the years I've built up a fairly unmanageable contact list.

I'm trying to delete old contacts that I no longer need, but I hate having text messages with no name associated with them so that's why I haven't bulk-deleted contacts so far.

Is there any way to find out which contacts are unused - as in contacts for which I have not received any text messages from?

Comment: Is "having no text messages from" the only criterium to be considered? Is your device rooted?

Comment: Maybe this app would help: [Contacts Optimizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.compelson.optimizer)

Comment: Yeah, that's the only criteria, and my phone is not rooted sadly @Izzy

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The app Sheharyar mentioned in his comment looks promising; maybe you could check it and let us know if it's a solution for you, so @Sheharyar might make it an answer?